# <asp:buttonfield> hooked up to a AsyncPostBackTrigger

Tags: .net, vb.net

How does one wire up an "asp:buttonfield" to an Update Panels AsyncPostBackTrigger?

I know it seems like a simple question, but AsyncPostBackTrigger requires a ControlID and "asp:buttonfield" does not have an "ID" attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't set ButtonField as Trigger. You can set TemplateField with Button and set onCommand for Button. After that, please set GridView as trigger.

Please check this thread: http://forums.asp.net/t/1322657.aspx